# Is it possible to forward to Siteminder login.fcc from a JSF action?

Tags: jsf, forward, siteminder

I have a "custom" (JSF) login page for my application. My company uses Siteminder for authentication. So, in order to login to Siteminder with a "custom" page, I have to have a form that posts to /login.fcc with the appropriate form fields (username/password and a couple of Siteminder specific hidden fields).

What I am trying to do is to continue to leverage the form validations and such of JSF and still post to login.fcc.

Here is a stripped down version of my custom form:

```
<rich:messages />
    <h:form id="adminLogin" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="center">
       <h:outputLabel value="HUB USERNAME:" />
       <h:inputText id="USER" label="Username" size="12" required="true" />
       <h:outputLabel value="HUB PASSWORD:" />
       <h:inputSecret id="PASSWORD" label="Password" size="12" required="true" />
       <input type="hidden" name="target" value="#{loginController.smTarget}" />
       <input type="hidden" name="smagentname" value="#{loginController.smAgentName}" />
     </h:panelGrid>
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="max-width button-panel">
     <a4j:commandButton id="adminLoginBtn" value="LOGIN"
       styleClass="login-btn" 
       action="#{loginController.managerLogin}" />
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Note that I have used standard hidden inputs for the target and smagentname fields. This is because I have no need to have both setters and getters in my controller for these fields. I simply want the controller to provide the values when the page renders.

My controller method looks like this:

```
public void managerLogin()
{
    LoginController.LOG.debug("manager is logging in...");
    LoginController.LOG.debug("user: " + getRequestParameterValue("USER"));
    LoginController.LOG.debug("smagent: " + getRequestParameterValue("smagentname"));
    LoginController.LOG.debug("target: " + getRequestParameterValue("target"));

    forwardTo(LoginController.SM_LOGIN_FCC);
}
```

You can see that I am logging the values from all fields except the password field and they all print correctly in my log...so I know I am getting the values.  My "forwardTo()" method simply gets the ExternalContext and calls dispatch() on it...passing in the path to the login.fcc page (which is "/forms/login.fcc").

When I input values in the form and click the login button, I see my values in the console but I get a 404 message in my browser.

I can manually put the "/forms/login.fcc" page in the address line and I have no problems with the GET rendering the login.fcc page. But I, of course, don't want to render the login.fcc (GET) I want to peform the Siteminder login (via POST).

It is my understanding that all request parameters are made available through a forward process I was expecting this to work.

I can take this same form and un-JSF-ize it...and make the login button simply submit the form (whose action would be the /forms/login.fcc via POST and it works fine too, but then I loose the benefits of the form/field validations that JSF provides.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to navigate to `http://<some_ip>:8080/<your_webapp>/forms/login.fcc` from a managed bean. Have you first tested the URL in a browser? If it works, how are you specifically trying to access to that URL (I mean, the `forwardTo` method code)?

Comment: @Luiggi - that got me to thinking...I may have a clue now.  So, Apache sits in front of our JBoss server and will see the /forms/login.fcc and send that request to the Siteminder agent to handle. So, technically it isn't hosted within the webapp since it is outside of JBoss. So, that being said I'm suspecting the forward will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Follow the SiteMinder redirect
- Send your credentials (username/password)
- Follow the SiteMinder redirect again
- Send the SiteMinder cookies

Here is an article which explains the process in detail:

- [How to Connect to a SiteMinder Protected Resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80314/How-to-Connect-to-a-SiteMinder-Protected-Resource)